Layer charge transfer and Interlayer coupling
I am studying TMD bilayers. I am interested in the interlayer coupling between them. I am applying an electric field to two different cases, one with an interlayer spacing (ILS) that is x times smaller than the equilibrium ILS and one y times bigger the equilibrium ILS. When reducing ILS the coupling strength increases, and the inverse happens when putting the layers further appart. When I then apply a potential drop to them I see that both experience a charge transfer from one layer to the other, being lower in the case of the system which has more separate layers as I was expecting.
However, while looking at the states in real space around the Gamma point, which correspond mostly to orbitals dz2 from the metal and pz orbitals from the chalcogen facing the interlayer and therefore (I assumed) they take an important part of the interactions between layers, I see that they react quite differently to the perturbation, having a great layer polarization in the case of lower coupling, that is, larger ILS. I am trying to reason why this could be. First thought was to argue that since there is lower wave function overlap, there is less charge forming the coupling between layers, and that charge is more 'free' to move or accomodate under a given perturbation. But while looking how the states at the K point look like in real space I noticed also a strong polarization, the less coupled the material is under the potential drop. So then does my argument still holds? am I missing something else?
